# Tips on how to create a function that will give me a max value from some data in a previous function

Tags: python, list, max

I am trying to create a function with data used in a previously made function that will return a pair consisting of the a specific max value and the list of the time at which this max value occurred.

any tips on how i would approach this?
I know for one that ill be using the max() function. any more help would be greatly appreciated as i am very new to this.

Comment: Please don't duplicate your question again !!

Comment: for first: add <body> after </head> and close </body> after all your html code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a margin-top and experiment with that add:

```
margin-top: (0px or -10px)
```

Also if that doesn't fix it try swapping to absolute position type.

Comment: -10px and switching to absolute position fixed it, thank you.

Comment: Np, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using CSS reset like this

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The reason this is happening is because by default browsers add a small margin around the document.

EDIT

You have also missed out the body tags in your code, after closing the head tag you should open the body tag and close it after all of your code (before closing the html tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the desired container `position: absolute; top:0;`

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first: always add  after the head section.... and close the HTML section

add in your HTML this:

```
 </head>
    <body>
      //all your html code
    </body>
```

Than add in your CSS code this:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  paddig:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code missing a body tag.

try this css

```
 body 
  {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You invalid html, after the head element, the main content should be in a body tag.  Fix that first and go from there.